# Meaning of run into

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **run into** in the following sentence

> Officials have spoken of soldiers being outnumbered when normal patrols with the strength of a few dozen each on the Indian side have **run into** Chinese forces that number in hundreds.

[**Link**](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/pla-actions-at-lac-in-ladakh-denote-shift-from-past-experts/article31665294.ece?homepage=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a definition of "run into":

[Merriam-Webster "run"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run%20into)
"run into"
2a : to collide with
 b : to meet by chance

A good alternative word for the given sentence would be "have encountered".